# Экспорт и импорт карты в конструкторе с сохранением типа и иконки маркера

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как экспортировать и импортировать карту, с переносом типа маркера и его иконкой, я видел способ эспортировать в geojson, но тип маркера там не прописан, если его добавить в ручную параметром options то он игнорируется при импорте

```
     "options": {
        "preset": "islands#blueFactoryCircleIcon"
     }
```

Comment: иконки через экспорт/импорт сохранить нельзя

Comment: Не нашёл возможности написать в личку. :-(
Можно узнать, где вы нашли экспорт в GeoJSON? Я никак не могу найти примера (кроме, конечно, руками из Конструктора, но нужна автоматизация).

Comment: @Fomalhaut если ещё актуально, про экспорт данных из Конструктора написано [тут](https://yandex.ru/support/maps-builder/concept/markers_3.html)